# Jbehave - full page screenshot

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, bdd, jbehave

I would like my application to take a screenshot when fail and I want this screenshot to be full screen, I am using this(which is taking the screenshot) however it is not full page.

```
new WebDriverScreenshotOnFailure(driverProvider, configuration.storyReporterBuilder()));
```

Answer (score 0):

for full page screen shot you can use the following method

```
final Screenshot screenshot = new AShot().shootingStrategy(
                new ViewportPastingStrategy(500)).takeScreenshot(driver);
        final BufferedImage image = screenshot.getImage();
        ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", new File(
                "D://"
                        + "AShot_BBC_Entire.png"));
```

Maven dependency is [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ru.yandex.qatools.ashot/ashot/1.4.12).

Now as far as i know there is no jBehave inbuild function for full page screenshot. Hence you can write this in a method and call it on failures.

Hope this helps.